# what's the difference between cat file and cat < file

Tags: unix

The way I understand this is that the command

```
cat file
```

will display the contents of file and

```
cat < file
```

will take the contents of file as input. I was trying this out and created two files. One called file1.txt and another one called file2.txt. In file1.txt, I wrote file2.txt, so by typing the command

```
cat < file1.txt
```

, I am expecting the content of file2.txt to be displayed; however , both
 `cat file1.txt and cat < file1.txt` 
are displaying the content of file1.txt. I think I am misunderstanding the definition of <.

Comment: refer to the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258931/difference-between-cat-and-cat

Answer (score 3):

When `cat` is run with argument files, it will open and read from each of these files to standard output. So with `cat file1.txt`, `cat` opens `file1.txt` and print its contents to standard output:

```
$ cat file1.txt
file2.txt
```

When `cat` is run with no argument files, it will read from standard input (e.g., as if you typed directly to cat) and write to standard output. But `< file1.txt` tells the *shell* (e.g., bash) to open the file `file1.txt`, and redirect it to `cat` through standard input:

```
$ cat < file1.txt
file2.txt
```

As you can see, the effect is the same, that cat will read the file given; the difference is who opens the file. In the first case, `cat` gets told to open the file itself, while in the second case the shell opens it, and `cat` doesn't know anything except that there's a stream of data coming in through its standard input, that it is supposed to print.

Finally, if you want to use the contents of `file1.txt` as an *argument* to `cat`, you need to use the syntax

```
$ cat $(< file1.txt) # same as: cat file2.txt
[...contents of file2.txt]
```

Comment: There is *no* piping involved with `cat < file1.txt`.  The input file is redirected, not piped.  `cat` can seek on stdin in this construction, whereas a seek will fail if the input is a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass one or more file names, `cat` will display the contents of those files. Otherwise, it will print whatever it is passed on stdin.

```
cat file
```

`cat` receives one file name, opens the file, and prints its contents

```
cat < file
```

The shell redirects stdin to the named file: it opens the file and feeds its contents to `cat` on stdin. `cat` receives no arguments. Without arguments, it prints whatever's on stdin—the contents of the file.

Net result: `cat file` and `cat < file` do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let see the concept of `cat` from its roots, say from plan9 (the evolved roots):

```
# \sys\src\cmd\cat.c

#include <u.h>
#include <libc.h>

void
cat(int f, char *s)
{
    char buf[8192];
    long n;

    while((n=read(f, buf, (long)sizeof buf))>0)
        if(write(1, buf, n)!=n)
            sysfatal("write error copying %s: %r", s);
    if(n < 0)
        sysfatal("error reading %s: %r", s);
}

void
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f, i;

    argv0 = "cat";
    if(argc == 1)
        cat(0, "<stdin>");
    else for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        f = open(argv[i], OREAD);
        if(f < 0)
            sysfatal("can't open %s: %r", argv[i]);
        else{
            cat(f, argv[i]);
            close(f);
        }
    }
    exits(0);
}
```

It's clear from the sources that if you give `< file` as argment to `cat` it reads from stdin (f=0) and writes to stdout (1):

```
    while((n=read(f, buf, (long)sizeof buf))>0)
        if(write(1, buf, n)!=n)
```